# Having an access exception with a mapped file being deleted

Tags: winapi

I want to simulate that an access to a file mapped into memory results in an access violation when the file is being delete while it is accessed through a mapping. That's my current code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

using XHANDLE = unique_ptr<void, decltype([]( void *h ) { h && h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE && CloseHandle( (HANDLE)h ); })>;
using XMAP_VIEW = unique_ptr<void, decltype([]( void *p ) { p && UnmapViewOfFile( p ); })>;

template<typename Fn, typename Filter, typename Handler>
    requires requires( Fn fn, Filter filter, EXCEPTION_POINTERS *pEp, Handler handler ) { { fn() }; { filter( pEp ) } -> same_as<LONG>; { handler() }; }
void seh_encapsulate( Fn fn, Filter filter, Handler handler );

int wmain( int argc, wchar_t **argv )
{
    if( argc < 2 )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    XHANDLE xhFile( CreateFileW( argv[1], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL ) );
    if( xhFile.get() == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    LARGE_INTEGER liFileSize;
    if( !GetFileSizeEx( xhFile.get(), &liFileSize ) || liFileSize.QuadPart > (size_t)-1 )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    XHANDLE xhMappging( CreateFileMapping( xhFile.get(), nullptr, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, nullptr ) );
    if( !xhMappging.get() )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    XMAP_VIEW mapView( MapViewOfFile( xhMappging.get(), FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0 ) );
    if( !mapView.get() )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    atomic_char
        *pa = (atomic_char *)mapView.get(),
        *paEnd = pa + (size_t)liFileSize.QuadPart;
    seh_encapsulate(
            [&]()
            {
                for( ; ; )
                    for( atomic_char *paScn = pa; paScn != paEnd; ++paScn )
                        (void)paScn->load( memory_order_relaxed );
            },
            [&]( EXCEPTION_POINTERS *pEp ) -> LONG
            {
                if( pEp->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode != EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR )
                    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
                if( pEp->ExceptionRecord->NumberParameters < 2 )
                    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
                void *where = (void *)pEp->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation[1];
                if( where < pa || where >= paEnd )
                    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
                return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
            },
            []()
            {
                cout << "I/O error" << endl;
            } );
}

template<typename Fn, typename Filter, typename Handler>
    requires requires( Fn fn, Filter filter, EXCEPTION_POINTERS *pEp, Handler handler ) { { fn() }; { filter( pEp ) } -> same_as<LONG>; { handler() }; }
void seh_encapsulate( Fn fn, Filter filter, Handler handler )
{
    __try
    {
        fn();
    }
    __except( filter( GetExceptionInformation() ) )
    {
        handler();
    }
}
```

"Unfortunately" I can delete the file but the clusters which occupied the file on the disk are retained until the mapping is closed.
Do you have any idea how I could make the clusters being unmapped so that my experiment will work ?

Aside from that the above code nicely shows how to have Structured Exception Handling "in" a function with stack-unwinding.

Comment: [`DeleteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-deletefile) marks a file for deletion, but the actual delete will not occur until the last handle to the file is closed. Since the file mapping object holds a handle to the file open for its lifetime you cannot actually delete the underlying file. If (for testing) you wish to raise an SEH exception, there's [RaiseException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-raiseexception) for that.

Comment: @IInspectable: If you delete a file while it is opened the name for the file vanishes in the filesystem, and you can re-create a file under the same name while the clusters of the file before remain opened; I've just checked that with a short program. I wanted to check if an exception is actually rised if an I/O error occurs. RaiseException() doesn't help for that.

Answer (score 0):

My intent was simply to find out if I/O errors occuring with a memory mapped file could be catched. My final idea was to copy a large file to an USB stick, unplug und plug it so that the cached data with that stick is flushed, then run the above program with that and unplug the stick while the code is running. And the result was like I expected: the I/O error results in an access violation which is caught by the above SEH handler.